# Can I use the verb+ing form here?

Tags: verb-forms

> The teachers should be helping hands to (flourish/flourishing) students hidden talent.

Is here using v+ing correct?

Comment: Helping hand means help or assistance and it's used singularly. The sentence should be: Teachers should be a helping hand in flourishing students' hidden talent.

Comment: You are using *flourish* incorrectly. The only time we use it as a transitive verb is when it means something like "to wave something around." See the Oxford Dictionary Online for example: [flourish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flourish)

Comment: We can change the word order of the sentence to solve that: "Teachers should have a helping hand in allowing students' hidden talent(s) to flourish".

Comment: This question was set up in an important public exam in our country,so it's hard to think that it's used in a wrong way.@δοῦλος

however, if I want to have the correct ans without changing the preposition(not 'in' but 'to') then what will be your suggestion? @All

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, the verb "flourish" has been placed in the sentence incorrectly. It's an intransitive verb, but it has been used as if it were a transitive verb.

The whole sentence needs to be rephrased. I think it should be as follows:

Teachers should give students a helping hand so that/in order that their hidden talents flourish.